# web3.py sendRawTransaction не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, web3.py, ethereum

Добрый вечер подскажите как отправить транзакцию подписав ее локально

делаю так:

```
to_addr = 0xbd0fc0e8245D099b751CF6437cc32385347F2251
from_addr = 0x00E49ef94dc7e798f4332e8E95303b24984F2c5e
key = 'ccbf6198479bd79d9cdcb7945a0212113d6a0428dc05e7ee82484c95cdd1d574'
gas_limit = 250000

transaction = {
    'to': to_addr,
    'from': from_addr,
    'value': 100,
    'gas': gas_limit,
    'gasPrice': 100000000,
    'chainId': 1,
    'nonce': int(time.time())
    }

   # signed_transaction = w3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, key)
   signed_transaction = w3.personal.signAndSendTransaction(transaction, key)
   raw_tx = rlp.encode(signed_transaction)
   raw_tx_hex = w3.toHex(raw_tx)
   print(raw_tx_hex) 

   transaction_id = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
```

но в ответ получаю такую ошибку ValueError: {'code': -32602, 'message': 'invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go struct field SendTxArgs.to of type common.Address'}

web3==3.16.4

уже все перепробовал, так и не получилось отправить транзакцию

Answer (score 0):

to_addr и from_addr должны быть строкой, а у вас int

```
>>> to_addr = 0xbd0fc0e8245D099b751CF6437cc32385347F2251
>>> type(to_addr)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: to_addr = '0xbd0fc0e8245D099b751CF6437cc32385347F2251'
from_addr = '0x00E49ef94dc7e798f4332e8E95303b24984F2c5e'
сделал строкой но ошибка не исчезла:
" raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32602, 'message': 'invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string without 0x prefix into Go value of type hexutil.Bytes'}" я уже просто не знаю куда копать, неделю убил на это :(